# Disable annoying PODAM logs

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, jemos-podam

I am using PODAM library to populate my POJOs with some random values and PODAM is spaming my logs. For 1 simple test I have more 6000+ lines in logs. I am only able to turn it off by adding.

**EDITED:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <logger name="uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl" level="INFO"/>-->
</configuration>
```

I am just wondering if there is another way how to achieve? *Looging.level.root=INFO* in application.properties doesnt help and I tried also *LogManager.getLogger(PodamFactoryImpl.class).setLevel(LogLevel.OFF)*

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code in your test or in setup() method:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setup() {
        Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger("uk.co.jemos.podam.api");
        root.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off logging for specific classes or packages in `application.properties` by adding `logging.level.<package-or-fully-qualified-class>=<log-level>`

For your case it might be something like:

`logging.level.uk.co.jemos.podam.api.PodamFactoryImpl=OFF`

Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels

Comment: Hi, what you mentioning I already tried and its true only if you are using @SpringBootTest or somehow initiating the properties. But my test is only @RunWith(SpringRunner) and the application properties are not initiated.

Comment: If you're not using `@SpringBootTest` there's probably more than just the properties not being initiated. Is there a reason you aren't?

Comment: Yes, its @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) I dont wanna use @SpringBootTest cause its too heavy weight just for filling few values..